# $scope variable not accessible from template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to create SPA with angular js.  Here is the code in my jsp page:

```
    <body class = "image1"  ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller  = "TasksController">

<div class="ng-view"></div>

</body>
 <script type = "text/javascript">

var mmyApp = angular.module('myApp',['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ngRoute']).controller('TasksController',  TasksController);
 function TasksController($scope, $http, $location) {


     $scope.searchString = null;
    $scope.shopping = {};

    var url = "/Online_Shopping/dispatcher/shopping/123";
     $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

        $scope.shoppings = response.data;


     }, function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
        $scope.selected = "";
        $scope.test = "hello";
     $scope.setSelected = function(shopping) {
                $scope.selected = shopping;
              console.log($scope.selected);

            $location.path("/item");
        };

     $scope.shoppingChanged = function()
     {
         var url = "/Online_Shopping/dispatcher/shopping/" + $scope.shopping;

         $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

             $scope.shoppings = response.data;

         }, function (error) {
             throw error;
         });

     };
 }

    mmyApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : '/Online_Shopping/shoppingtable.jsp',
                controller  : 'TasksController'
            })


            .when('/item', {
                templateUrl : '/Online_Shopping/item.jsp',
                controller  : 'TasksController'
            })


    });
 </script>
```

The console prints out the proper information for `$scope.selected`, but when I try to access it from my view template, nothing shows up.

Here is my view template, item.jsp - it works for `{{test}}` but not for `{{selected}}`:

```
<h1>$scope.test is equal to {{test}}</h1>
<h2>$scope.selected is equal to {{selected}}</h2>
```

edit: I initialized $scope.selected in my code as the comments say, but I'm still getting no value from $scope.selected in the view template.  It appears that the controller function is recalled when I use $location to redirect to /items.  Is there any way to prevent this recalling of the controller when I switch views?

Comment: `$scope.selected` is within the method which means it is not initiated. You have try putting `$scope.selected = ""` before the method. And see if it works.

Comment: Are you calling '$scope.setSelected' by any event and passing  shopping data properly, try to pass static value in function.

Comment: Can you post fiddle?

Comment: I added in initializing $scope.selected - see edited post, yet $scope.selected is still equal to nothing in the view.

Answer (score 0):

when you first run the app, you should get

> <h2>$scope.selected is equal to</h2>

but then when you call the event, or function using some method, like for example a button using ng-click, or in a initial method, or a callback of a timeout and many other things that exist, if you call the *setSelected*, you will get:

> <h2>$scope.selected is equal to <value of shopping variable></h2>

here is a sample:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="setSelected('xyz')"/>
```

or

```
---controller begin---
...
     $scope.test = "hello";
     $scope.setSelected = function(shopping) {
                $scope.selected = shopping;
              console.log($scope.selected);
            $location.path("/item");
        };
...
    function initialize(){
        $scope.setSelected("xyz");
    }
    initialize();
---controller end---
```

will return:

> <h2>$scope.selected is equal to xyz</h2>

**ALSO NOTE** That `this`, point to the object itself, not the function body, and the `shopping` you called on this (`this.shopping`) is different from `shopping` object you set as parameter of the function. if you did not defined the shopping on the controller it self, you will probably get `undefined` value, and you left the `shopping` parameter unused.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect changes but still getting nothing for $scope.selected.  The console properly returns $scope.selected value but it appears that when going to the /items view, scope.selected is erased or the controller is called again?

Comment: @PaymonWang-Lotfi if your element which contain ng-controller get remove and then recreate it may restart controller, otherwise i never see it happen. (or ng-view if you use router, not until you switch pages)...

Comment: @PaymonWang-Lotfi First, i'm not sure what exactly you did, but from my point of view, you create a layout, you add a parent controller, to control shared data, then you also have your sub-route-based-controllers, which you didn't identify. they may or may not affect the data on this controller... Second: your application run as following: it set searchString to null and shopping to object, you set the ur, you call a get operation, you set selected to empty string, set test to hello, then set setSelected to a custom function, and set shoppingChanged to another function,(i continue in next post

Comment: after this, the operation meet end of controller bracket, and sync operation  finishes, after sometime, which you never notice, the data will return from server, and the get operation success or fail will launch, it either will throw error, or set $scope.shopping to the received data.  setSelected or shoppingChanged, will never run by the code i see. and i'm yet unaware of the data which will load in ng-view, using config section, as you did not provide the pages or the controllers

Answer (score 0):

In angular to  get the binding working properly you need to declare the variable or initialize the scope variable to get this working properly .

In your case `selected` is not initialized but the `test` is thats why test is working but `selected` is not. Add `$scope.selected=''` to make it work .

Comment: I updated code in my post to reflect that change but still getting nothing for $scope.selected.